# How to print multiple items in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This question seems like a silly question because its very basic, but I really am struggling. I have a constantly updating stream of data coming from python-binance web socket that is the prices of current currencies within the market. I am trying to separate the symbols and prices that comes when using the line:

```
info = client.get_all_tickers()
```

which prints the following which will be a section of the output:

```
[{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.06327900'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00406800'}, ...]
```

My aim is to isolate the symbol and price and have them printed next to each other instead of having the phrases 'symbol' and 'price' so I can both complete math equations on the prices, and so I can also output the two values in a beautified way.

I've tried this so far:

```
symbolGetter = [ swap['symbol'] for swap in info ]
```

to get my symbol and:

```
priceGetter = [ swap['price'] for swap in info ]
```

This only gets them separately, but trying to print them next to eachother using these methods that I thought would work:

```
symbolAndPriceGetter = [ swap['symbol', 'price'] for swap in info ]
print(symbolAndPriceGetter)
```

This throws me the error:

```
KeyError: ('symbol', 'price')
```

Trying another way:

```
symbolGetter = [ swap['symbol', 'price'] for swap in info ]
priceGetter = [ swap['price'] for swap in info ]
print(symbolGetter, priceGetter)
```

returns me the symbols printed in one list and then prices printed in another list.

How could I go about returning (symbol, price)(symbol, price)...

Thankyou for any help

Comment: `[(swap['symbol'], swap['price']) for swap in info ]`?

Comment: `[ swap['symbol'] +':' + swap['price'] for swap in info ]` ? Because the values are string, you can concatenate these. I have put a : in the middle to separate it. You can create a tuple of symbol value with price value, as suggested by @Matthias

Answer (score 1):

You can format each item into a string like this:

```
stringified = ['{0} {1}'.format(swap["symbol"], swap["price"]) for swap in info]
```

And then you can print each of them:

```
for s in stringified:
    print(s)
```

Or in a single operation:

```
print('\n'.join(stringified))
```

Both will result in:

```
ETHBTC 0.06327900
LTCBTC 0.00406800
```

On the other hand, if you wanted to write it to a csv, you can use `csv.DictWriter` for that purpose:

```
with open('swaps.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['symbol', 'price']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(info)
```

Comment: This removes the list, very smart, and if I were to export it to a csv file I would with open .... wouldn't I

Comment: If you want to export to a csv file, keep the dictionaries and use `csv.DictWriter`

Comment: @sabik is correct. I have updated my answer to describe writing to a csv.

Comment: With an f-string: `stringified = [f'{swap["symbol"]} {swap["price"]}' for swap in info]`

Comment: I also prefer f-strings, but I don't know what version of Python OP is running

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for a in info:
    print(list(a.values()))
```

You will get:

```
['ETHBTC', '0.06327900']
['LTCBTC', '0.00406800']
```

An alternative solution would be this:

```
for a in info:
    print(*a.values())
```

You will get:

```
ETHBTC 0.06327900
LTCBTC 0.00406800
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import Decimal

dl = [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.06327900'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00406800'}]

res = [(d['symbol'], Decimal(d['price'])) for d in dl]
print(res)
# [('ETHBTC', Decimal('0.06327900')), ('LTCBTC', Decimal('0.00406800'))]

# Then for example if you want aveage of price
prices = [t[1] for t in res]
ave_price = sum(prices) / (len(prices))
print(ave_price)
# 0.03367350
```

Comment: Probably not ideal to use `float`; prefer `Decimal` or keep them as strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can put expressions in the list comprehension, eg:

```
prices_as_tuples = [ (swap['symbol'], swap['price']) for swap in info ]
```

Or, to format it up as text

```
prices_for_printing = [ "%s at %s" % (swap['symbol'], swap['price']) for swap in info ]

print("; ".join(prices_for_printing))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the values of each dictionary and print them using generator

```
print(*(' '.join(v for v in d.values()) for d in info), sep='\n')

# ETHBTC 0.06327900
# LTCBTC 0.00406800
```